# How to create a simple GUI to execute a powershell script by using the tools already present in Windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, user-interface

Is it possible to create a simple GUI for executing a powerscript with the help of only those tools which are already present in WIndows 8.1. Without installing any third party tool?

Comment: Yes, you can use Notepad. For the simple GUI, it might be that you're looking for something like [PowerShell Tip: Creating a Custom Input Box](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730941.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. I Always use "PrimalForms Community Edition". It schould be free to download and is breatty nice. You can draw any forms and export it to powershell code.